(spring boot) can't resolve symbol 'validation' jdkversion:11 springboot version:2.6.1311
[it highlights 3bugs,
as you see,i am trying to add revelent dependencies into the pom.xml,but it doesn't work, how to fix it?
the language level of the project structure is 11
The sdk's name is 11
The target bytecode version is 11](https://i.sstatic.net/Yj2I53ox.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/EDNLxPPZ.jpg)
How to solve it, please 

details:Can not resolve symbol 'Valid'. Can't resolve symbol 'Errors'.Can not resolve method 'hasErrors()'

Please add the imports for the class that is showing these errors. Looking for javax.validation.* vs jakarta.validation.*

Thank you guys , your suggestions are very useful,

Sometimes, a clean and rebuild of the project can resolve dependency issues. In your IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), you can try this by:

Clicking on Build in the top menu.
Selecting Rebuild Project.

Please also check imports in OrderController.java and ensure that all necessary imports are present at the top of your file.
